# What happens when salt water is electrolyzed with a copper anode and a copper cathode?

Tags: electrolysis

I heard that copper oxide is formed on the cathode and copper chloride is formed on the anode, is this correct?
I don't have much knowledge of chemistry, so I can't find out much by searching on Google.

Comment: No copper oxide should be formed on the cathode. The only thing that should occur at the cathode is the formation of $\ce{H2}$ bubbles, plus some $\ce{OH^-}$ in solution. After a long time, the $\ce{OH^-}$ ions formed at the cathode should be mixed with $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ formed at the anode, and a blue precipitate of $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ should be the consequence, due to the reaction $\ce{Cu^{2+} + 2 OH^- -> Cu(OH)2}$. That's all.

Comment: Maurice, I am afraid your last part of explanation is quite incorrect. There is no blue precipitate. Instead an orange precipitate forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chemistry here can be explained from the associated products of the electrolysis of brine. To quote an [education source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/17%3A_Electrochemical_Cells/17.03%3A_Electrolysis_of_Brine):

> Three important chemicals, NaOH, Cl2, H2, can be obtained by electrolyzing an aqueous NaCl solution (brine). This forms the basis of the chlor-alkali industry. The diaphragm cell (also called a Hooker cell)...

As such, depending on the cell design, expect also hypochlorous acid:

$\ce{Cl2 (g) + H2O (l) <-> HCl (aq) + HOCl(aq) }$

and hypochlorite with OH- as a side product of the electrolysis of the brine:

$\ce{ OH- + HOCl -> H2O + ClO-}$

However, some of the $\ce{HOCl}$ can also engage in a Fenton-type reaction ([example here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275818872_Influence_of_Chelating_Agents_on_Fenton-Type_Reaction_Using_Ferrous_Ion_and_Hypochlorous_Acid/link/5780e3c308ae69ab88262a03/download)) with $\ce{Cu}$ (and, to a lesser extent, $\ce{HOCl}$ acting on $\ce{Cu2O}$ resulting in some possible $\ce{CuO}$ or even a basic chloride formation) generally depicted as follows:

$\ce{Cu/Cu+ + HOCl -> Cu+/Cu++ + .OHCl-}$

where the latter radical intermediate can further break down with products dependent on the pH level (here, likely over pH 7 from $\ce{OH-}$ created in the parallel electrolysis reaction) and the chloride concentration. Source: See reactions listed in Supplement Table S1 [available here](http://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/22/10/1684) by clicking on *Supplement File* to obtain a download.

Support: With metal spoons serving as electrodes for the electrolysis of a saltwater solution, there is clear discoloration of one of the spoon electrodes (visible at 5 minutes and 20 seconds into this [science experiment video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-OwWOYHhMI)).

Bottomline in time, expect similar discoloration of a copper electrode as well from the associated electrolysis products.

Comment: All points in my answer are now fully sourced.

Comment: Great answer +1, but could you please elaborate on the reactions on the copper electrodes? I tried to build a faraday motor, see several youtube movies, but observed that after a few minutes some dark corrosion occurs on the copper electrodes that obstructs the current flow. Or perhaps the amount of ions is reduced which reduces current? Should I try different metals for the electrodes?